# Trying to connect Laravel with DB2 database with odbc driver

Tags: php, laravel, db2, odbc, db2-400

I'm on a Laravel 5.2 based project, I've to connect it with a DB2 database hosted on an IBM i-series server, I've tried some plugins but this one seems to correspond to my needs :
https://github.com/bencarter78/odbc
I followed the installation steps, filled the database.php file, created a model and a controller but the page keeps returning :

> PDOException in Connector.php line 55: invalid data source name

There is my controller :

```
<?php  

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\didactp1;

class didactitiel extends Controller  
{  
    public function recupererDidactitiels()
    {  
        $didactitiels = didactp1::all();  
        return view('didactitiel')->with('didactitiels', $didactitiels);  
    }  
}
```

My model :

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class didactp1 extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'odbc';
}
```

But I think the problem comes from the database.php file configuration but I can't find what's wrong :

```
'odbc' => [
            'driver'   => 'odbc',
            'dsn'      => 'AS400',
            'host'     => 'TheIpOfTheHostingServer',
            'database' => 'myDatabaseName',
            'username' => 'com11',
            'password' => 'pcs400',
        ],
```

I tried to connect to the database manually with unixODBC :
[error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tboZc.png)
[odbc.ini](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqjg5.png)
I also tried the $sudo iptables -L command
[iptables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Vynq.png)
Hope that's clear enought, every kind of help is welcome

Comment: Does the DSN work on your workstation outside of PHP?  If Ms-Windows does odbcad32 connect to the DSN? If Linux, does isql work with the DSN?

Comment: With linux it doesn't work ( captures in the ( updated ) post )

Comment: Please google how to configure unixodbc with a DSN in files /etc/odbc.ini and /etc/odbcinst.ini.  You will need an odbc driver for accessing the i-series (either open source jt400 or the IBM i-series access driver(needs licence)).  This is configuration (not programming). You can also connect without a DSN if preferred (DSN less).

Comment: I'm struggling to install the odbc driver, if it can help you, I made a program 2 weeks ago in php (native) and jquery, and to get the informations i needed from the database i was using the odbc driver (which is installed on the server where the program is and where my actual project in laravel is) to make sql queries, and it is working perfectly (the dsn used was "AS400", user "com11" and password "pcs400"). That's why i think the problem comes from me not configurating correctly the plugin rather than the dsn being wrong.

Comment: Which odbc driver are you using or trying to install? What version? What error do you get when you try to install it?  Continue your research.

Comment: So I installed the odbc driver snowflake (https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/odbc-linux.html), I got an error (put it in the post), it seems like I misconfigured something, but it detects the DSN ( when i change it in the odbc.ini it tells me that it can't found it ) and the host address  (same as for DSN), so i don't understand what i'm missing

Comment: the connection refused in the error.log could be related to the firewall ? could you post iptables -L as root and remove the rules if necessary.

Comment: I uptaded the post with the thing you asked, but i don't understand what it means, also i tried to disable the firewall, but i got the same error.